# Call value from function into Private Sub _Click button event (ACCESS VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

How can I get a value from Function (in a module) and insert it into variable within the `Private Sub _Click()` event button?

My code for function is (I need to get Sheetname):

```
Public Function GetExcelWorksheet(path As String, Sheetname As String) As Worksheet
    OpenExcelWorkbook (path)
    Set GetExcelWorksheet = m_OpenWorkbook.Sheets(Sheetname)
End Function
```

My `Private Sub _Click()` is (button on form):

```
Private Sub RinominaSalvaTabella_Click()
Dim NomeFoglio As String
NomeFoglio = GetExcelWorksheet(Sheetname)
DoCmd.Rename "T_Temp", acTable, Sheetname
End Sub
```

Many thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Put `Sheetname` in a `Public/Global` var. Then I'd use additional vars to indicate whether the `Sheetname` is initialized and (still) valid.

Comment: Hi AcsErno, now it works. many thanks. Andrea

Answer (score 0):

You simple use

```
Dim NomeFoglio As Excel.Worksheet 'supposing that a reference to Excel Application exists
Set NomeFoglio = GetExcelWorksheet(Sheetname)
```

instead of

```
Dim NomeFoglio As String
NomeFoglio = GetExcelWorksheet(Sheetname)
```

But if you need the sheet name (as string) for the line `DoCmd.Rename "T_Temp", acTable, Sheetname`, all the code before it is useless... You should adapt it like this, but no sense to proceed in this way: `DoCmd.Rename "T_Temp", acTable, NomeFoglio.Name`

You did not share the code for `OpenExcelWorkbook` which should be another function. It probably returns a workbook. Possible `Set m_OpenWorkbook = OpenExcelWorkbook (path)`. Otherwise, `m_OpenWorkbook` is not defined.

I answered the question as it is, but can you better explain what you want accomplishing? Are you only playing with VBA to see what happens?

Comment: @Andrea Mario Labate: Glad I could help! If it works due to my help... It this is the case, we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the answer helped...